# $ variable and javascript/jquery question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently solved a jquery problem I had by switching all the '$'s in my code to 'jQuery'

I'm trying to use this code:

```
var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
$items.mouseover(function() {
    $items.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var index = $items.index($(this));
    $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
}).eq(1).mouseover();
```

but am not sure how to change the $ signs out for $items. Is it as simple as jQuery.items? Is this even jQuery code? I'm confused.

Thanks,
Zeem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$items` does not need to be changed. jQuery's variable is (typically) just a `$`, whereas `$items` is it's own variable name.

So your code would become:

```
var $items = jQuery('#vtab>ul>li');
$items.mouseover(function() {
    $items.removeClass('selected');
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected');

    var index = $items.index(jQuery(this));
    jQuery('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
}).eq(1).mouseover();
```

**Edit**
You could also use a [self-invoking function](http://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/advanced-javascript/) like so:

```
(function($){
    var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
    $items.mouseover(function() {
        $items.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var index = $items.index($(this));
        $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
    }).eq(1).mouseover();
})(jQuery);
```

This will allow you to use the `$` variable in your code BUT you will not be able to use the variables within, outside of the function so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace $items at all.

```
$items = jQuery('#vtab>ul>li');
```

will work.

$items is a variable name and is not part of the $ namespace.

Answer (score 1):

`var $items` is just a variable. Prefixing variables with `$` lets the developer know that it's a jQuery object.